# npm install not installing any package

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I run the command `npm install package-name`, it doesn't show any error and it also does not install the package(no `node_modules` folder, just does nothing). Here is the kind of message I get:

> up to date, audited 248 packages in 11s
>
> 8 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> 19 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 9 high, 4 critical)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:   npm audit fix
>
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:   npm audit
> fix --force
>
> Run `npm audit` for details.

I have also tried `npm i package-name` and `npm install --save package-name`, but all give the same message. I'm currently using Node version `18.12.1`.

What could I be doing wrong and what could be causing this issue?

Comment: How do you check if `node_modules` has been created?

Comment: the terminal comand ```ls```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. The fix was to initialize `npm` in the folder. I ran `npm init -y` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install npm packages locally, you should run the
`npm init`
command first.
A file called **package.json** will be created  which contains basic information about the project and the dependencies used in it.
Then in the same directory run the installation command.

Answer (score 0):

It often happens when your project has more than the required cache. You can do the following to remove the cache:

- Run **npm cache clean --force** in your terminal
- Run **cd android** to jump to the android folder (if you're using react native cli), then again run **./gradlew clean**. Go back to your project folder by typing **cd ..**

Now, install your package and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Alternative solution . try with this command**

> npm i --legacy-peer-deps

**is may fix your issue. if your issue didnt solved with this, try yarn ..**

> npm i yarn -g

**and then in your project directory**

> yarn